# Image rumble in Android app

Tags: android, image, animation

I have a quiz of sorts. There are a couple images at the top.  What I'd like to do is when a wrong answer is given, rumble one if the images for a second or two and have it settle back into position.  Just a small shake in the X and Y.  Is this doable?  The images are in the same layout as the rest.  I don't know if that matters.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a demo of this in the API Demos, under Views/Animation/Shake.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a simple View animation to alter the position as outlined at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html.